# BindTransportException when trying to start elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to start my elasticsearch server by running bin/elasticsearch from my ES directory but I keep getting a bindtransport exception. What should I do?

```
 idea!
[2016-08-11 04:57:45,143][INFO ][node                     ] [anish-elk1] version[2.3.3], pid[30342], build[218bdf1/2016-05-17T15:40:04Z]
[2016-08-11 04:57:45,143][INFO ][node                     ] [anish-elk1] initializing ...
[2016-08-11 04:57:45,683][INFO ][plugins                  ] [anish-elk1] modules [lang-groovy, reindex, lang-expression], plugins [], sites []
[2016-08-11 04:57:45,707][INFO ][env                      ] [anish-elk1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/xvda1)]], net usable_space [16.1gb], net total_space [49gb], spins? [no], types [ext4]
[2016-08-11 04:57:45,707][INFO ][env                      ] [anish-elk1] heap size [990.7mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2016-08-11 04:57:47,647][INFO ][node                     ] [anish-elk1] initialized
[2016-08-11 04:57:47,648][INFO ][node                     ] [anish-elk1] starting ...
Exception in thread "main" BindTransportException[Failed to bind to [9300-9400]]; nested: ChannelException[Failed to bind to: /192.168.0.1:9400]; nested: BindException[Cannot assign requested address];
Likely root cause: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:391)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:315)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

elasticsearch.yml

```
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
# name that es uses to find other clusters to join
# when you turn on a node, it will find other nodes on the network to talk to
# if found, it will cluster. name determines if node will join or not.
cluster.name: elk1
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
# everytime you turn on a node, it will choose a marvel comic character
# node.name is just a name
node.name: anish-elk1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
# node.rack: r1
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
# path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
# path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
# allows jvm to lock memory on startup to avoid swapping
bootstrap.mlockall: true
#
# Make sure that the `ES_HEAP_SIZE` environment variable is set to about half the memory
# available on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
# setting to control network traffic. only allows traffic from :<> so that
# external processes cannot access elasticsearch server
# network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
# http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html>
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
# discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of nodes / 2 \
+ 1):
#
# discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, see the documentation at:
# <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html>
...(everthing commenteed)
```

Comment: What configuration do you have in your `elasticsearch.yml` file for the `transport.tcp.port` setting? Do you already have something running on port 9400?

Comment: have you been starting/stopping your ES server very frequently? It can be that you've consumed all the ports in the 9300-9400 range they are still in a CLOSE_WAIT state. make sure that `network.tcp.reuse_address` is set to true.

Comment: How can i check if i have something running on port 9400?

Comment: this is running on a vm so it's possible that it's been restarted, but i personally haven't restarted it

Comment: i don't have `transport.tcp.port` or `network.tcp.reuse_address` in my elasticsearch.yml